# Remus on Amazon EC2: If and When?

Tags: amazon-ec2, xen

Slashdot recently [brought word](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/11/11/2246226) that the Remus project (which implements hot-backup Xen instances) has been merged into the core Xen. Since Amazon have leveraged Xen in building out EC2, I naturally can't help but wonder if Remus:

- has been deployed as part of EC2?
- has been considered by Amazon for use with EC2?
- has been rejected for some reason(s) unknown to me?

The possibilities introduced to the realities of EC2 by Remus make me want to jump out of my pants. If anyone knows anything on the subject, please post an answer.

Comment: Given that I recently moved my http://bugcollect.com on EC2 you can understand my surprise at reading the title of the post...

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised because we live in the twilight zone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remus is still young, eight months since first release.  I feel that it could be useful technology for Amazon once it has matured sufficiently.  I feel that Amazon will wait for Remus to stabilize, get a happy pool of users, get the bugs out of the system, and see the results of other smaller sites using it.

Amazon EC2 is big so if they make a new feature go live, I think they will have thousands of people hitting them with support issues for any tiny thing that might go wrong!

Give it a year or two perhaps?

Comment: Amazon is also pretty good at rolling out trial services, and having this would really benefit their checkbox comparison to other cloud services.  I suspect it will be sooner, but not in production for at least 1-2 years as mentioned.

Comment: is it possible to update the answer. curious about the state of Remus